# Can the same model classify + predict continuous values?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, regression

Suppose I have a dataset of photos of dogs. There is only a single dog per photograph. What does the output vector for a single sample look like, and how do I train the network if I want it to:

- predict the age (in days) of the dog in the picture
- classify the dog's gender
- classify the dog's breed
- predict (x,y) coordinates of dog's nose within the picture (where each coordinate is a value between 0-1, indicating percentage of the distance from top left corner of the input image)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use only one model for that kind of problem.

However, your model will have a 5-fold architecture as follows:

1. A first "core" model taking in input your dog photos
2. A second model taking in input the output of the core model and predicting the age
3. A third model taking in input the output of the core model and predicting the gender
4. A fourth model taking in input the output of the core model and predicting the breed
5. A fifth model taking in input the output of the core model and predicting the coordinates...

While theoretically feasible, this may be a bit cumbersome to put in place in order to have good results for all models.

That is more or less what google brain did [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05137) (except that their models are more diverse).

PS: For this kind of question, you should rather ask them on stats.stackexchange.com or datascience.stackexchange.com